# why I cant's run this method (openlayers)(ol.layer.Vector)

Tags: openlayers

```js
   
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: features
    });
    
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        
        style: function (feature) {
            feature.setStyle(typeitems(feature));
            console.log("apple");
        }
    });
```

this is my code.
why can't run this line console.log("apple"); in ol.layer.Vector ?

Comment: sorry, I edited~ ^^

Answer (score 0):

The `style` property will apply a `ol.Style | ol.Style[] | ol.StyleFunction` to all the features that don't have their own style.

If you post the complete sample we could probably help you better. However, I am going to suppose that the styling function signature is something like `function typeitems(feature: ol.Feature): ol.Style`. In this case you could rewrite your code like this:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,

    style: function (feature) {
        return typeitems(feature);
    }
});

[...]

function typeitems(feature: ol.Feature): ol.Style {
    return new ol.Style({
        stroke: new ol.Style.Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 5})
    });
}
```

In here, `typeitems()` is kinda pointless as it will always create the same red stroke style, but you get my point on how you could approach your problem. If you need more specific help, please post more related code than such a minimal variable declaration.

Good luck!